# JoomShaper Simple Image Gallery Module extention not working in joomla3

Tags: joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

i need to use good image gallery for joomla 3 site.i got a extention.it's name simple gallery module.i installed it to my system.i need to get images for some article by using this module.i used

```
[gallery]pos[/gallery]
```

code in my article..but not working this.then i used

```
{gallery}pos{/gallery}
```

that code..it is also not working.please any one can help me solving this problem..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to display a module using plug-in syntax.

To include a module in an article, configure the module to use a custom module position name e.g. "position-name" and then use the following syntax in your article: `{loadposition position-name}`.

Alternatively, install a slideshow plug-in instead such as the Simple Image Gallery plug-in:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/content-photo-gallery/1468